# Zapier Code: Transform String to Array javascript

Tags: javascript, json, zapier

I have a webhook which receives data in a string format:

```
"{\"id\":\"2119813016789714851\",\"auth0_id\":\"auth0|5bbef2b54dac115c7a86684b\",\"title\":null,\"first_name\":\"Gary\",\"last_name\":\"Richard\",\"date_of_birth\":\"1994-04-10T00:00:00.000Z\",\"phone\":\"+44123456789\",\"company_id\":\"2119813365948745637\",\"status\":\"NEEDS_REVIEW\",\"email\":\"demo-1@lendflo.com\",\"agree_lendflo\":true,\"agree_authorized\":true,\"delete_director_id\":null,\"mail_change_code\":null,\"postcode\":\"ng72du\",\"address\":\"10 Faraday Road, Nottingham, Nottinghamshire\",\"country\":\"United Kingdom\",\"name\":\"fdsqfdsqfdsq\",\"company_house_no\":\"485245874\",\"main_contact_first_name\":\"Gary\",\"main_contact_last_name\":\"Richard\",\"registered_address\":\"fdsqfdsqfdsq\",\"trading_address\":null,\"website\":null,\"last_year_revenue\":\"123456\",\"registered_address_postcode\":\" LE1 6RP\",\"trading_address_postcode\":null,\"vat_number\":null,\"employee_count\":0,\"primary_user\":\"2119813016789714851\",\"company_status\":\"SIGNUP_INCOMPLETE\",\"companyIndustries\":[{\"sic\":\"62090\",\"label\":\"Other information technology service activities\"},{\"sic\":\"64992\",\"label\":\"Factoring\"}],\"stage\":\"dev\"}"
```

I need to convert that string to JSON and put it in an array so that it can be ready by subsequent actions of the zap.

I am trying to do with the code module in javascript with this code

```
output = []
var data = JSON.parse(input.data)
output.push(data)
```

But i get an error:

```
We had trouble sending your test through.
You must return a single object or array of objects.
```

**UPDATE**
Here is a print screen of the actual editor.
I am really confused on what could go wrong here:
[image]

Comment: Everything you've shown here looks like it would work fine, it's valid json that correctly converts to an object. Maybe that error is wrong and it's looking for the single data object instead of being in an array?

Comment: I guess this is why i am here, I don't get what I am doing wrong, according to their docs here is what it says about the input: What input data should we provide to your code (as strings) via an object set to a variable named inputData?

Comment: I have pretty much set up exactly what you have and the test goes through no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Very odd! I did a quick spot check and mine works as expected:

[image]

[image]

I sent this webhook with the following command:

`curl https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/USER_ID/HOOK_ID/ -XPOST -d '{"very": "cool"}'`

I notice that in your input, your json seems to be wrapped in another set of strings? I double checked that my `inputData.webhook` was indeed a string. Maybe verify that on your end? You can also simplify the code a little:

```js
return {
  inputType: typeof inputData.webhook, // should be "string"
  outputType: typeof JSON.parse(inputData.webhook), // should be "object"
  output: JSON.parse(inputData.webhook) // should be your actual data, split out
}
```

That should help you get in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

it works well i think your `input.data` is not the right input

```js
const data = "{\"id\":\"2119813016789714851\",\"auth0_id\":\"auth0|5bbef2b54dac115c7a86684b\",\"title\":null,\"first_name\":\"Gary\",\"last_name\":\"Richard\",\"date_of_birth\":\"1994-04-10T00:00:00.000Z\",\"phone\":\"+44123456789\",\"company_id\":\"2119813365948745637\",\"status\":\"NEEDS_REVIEW\",\"email\":\"demo-1@lendflo.com\",\"agree_lendflo\":true,\"agree_authorized\":true,\"delete_director_id\":null,\"mail_change_code\":null,\"postcode\":\"ng72du\",\"address\":\"10 Faraday Road, Nottingham, Nottinghamshire\",\"country\":\"United Kingdom\",\"name\":\"fdsqfdsqfdsq\",\"company_house_no\":\"485245874\",\"main_contact_first_name\":\"Gary\",\"main_contact_last_name\":\"Richard\",\"registered_address\":\"fdsqfdsqfdsq\",\"trading_address\":null,\"website\":null,\"last_year_revenue\":\"123456\",\"registered_address_postcode\":\" LE1 6RP\",\"trading_address_postcode\":null,\"vat_number\":null,\"employee_count\":0,\"primary_user\":\"2119813016789714851\",\"company_status\":\"SIGNUP_INCOMPLETE\",\"companyIndustries\":[{\"sic\":\"62090\",\"label\":\"Other information technology service activities\"},{\"sic\":\"64992\",\"label\":\"Factoring\"}],\"stage\":\"dev\"}"

const output = []
const json = JSON.parse(data)

output.push(json)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: I have checked again, renamed in the actual variable nothing works... Please see update above in a print screen